# Django PasswordChangeForm in view.py not working

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to implement the change-password functionality using Django, but it's not working. Seems like it always render a new form without going into the form_valid statement, without giving any error informations also.

Here is my code in my views.py

```
def password_reset_by_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
            return render(request, 'check_success.html')
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)

    context = {'form': form, }
    return render(request, 'user/reset_by_user.html', context)
```

I'm wondering what I did wrong, please help me. Thank you

Comment: I import the PasswordChangeForm from django.contrib.auth.forms

Comment: You did not handled when the input values to form is not valid. if form.is_valid() need to have an else condition.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you redirect after the password change, and that there is a valid user session before the view is called.

Try this version:

```
from django.contrib.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash

@login_required
def password_reset_by_user(request):
   form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user data=request.POST or None)
   if form.is_valid():
     form.save()
     update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
     return redirect('/')
   return render(request, 'users/reset_by_user.html', {'form': form})
```

You can also use the built-in [`PasswordChangeView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordChangeView), and just pass your custom template:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordChangeView

class PasswordResetByUser(PasswordChangeView):
  template_name = 'users/reset_by_user.html'
  success_url = '/'
```

Comment: hello I tried your version, I still get the same problem. The process never saved the new password or redirect and just keep rendering the reset page.